# How to handle anomaly detections with multiple different timeseries' from network traffic?

Tags: neural-networks, time-series, anomaly-detection

I would like to implement an anomaly detection algorithm on multiple timeseries' from different network users. Since each user has different behavior and network traffic usage, my question is how can I implement an anomaly detection algorithm for this case? If possible I would like to have the model to be trained on online data, meaning when new data arrives it should be able to use that data, so that I dont need to train it over and over again.
When dealing with new users, it should consider other users as reference and not immediately trigger an anomaly.

I was thinking about training an ensemble model of LSTMs with different temporal properties such as sequences of minutes, hours, days, weeks, months in order to predict successfully short-term anomalys and long-term occurences. Does anyone else had the same problem in the past?

Answer (score 0):

If you want "the model to be trained on online data, meaning when new data arrives it should be able to use that data, so that I dont need to train it over and over again.", then DAMP can do this, at over 100,000 Hz  [a]
[a] [https://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/DAMP_long_version.pdf](https://www.cs.ucr.edu/%7Eeamonn/DAMP_long_version.pdf)